# How to connect list of objects to node in Relay

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

In GraphQL, I have the following structure

```
# represents any node with GlobalIdField
node(id: "uniqueIdOfNode") {
   
}

# represents actually logged user
viewer {

}
```

In [sample MVC app schema](https://github.com/taion/relay-todomvc/blob/master/src/data/schema.js) todos are connected to the viewer so when querying you can get only those todos that belong to logged user.

However, in my case, I want to display data which is not related to a user. Let's say data is type Country which is NodeInterfaceType and I want to make a query where I ask for the list of countries. So in Relay, I can make fragment on CountryList where I get a country and pass it to React component using Relay.

If what I've written is not clear enough let me know because I'm confused with it and I'm not sure if I explained it well.

I've written GraphQL server in PHP but the code or hints can be written in node.js and I'll understand it as well.

How to do it?

## Update

Some code:

**schema.graphql**

```
# A country
type Country implements NodeInterface {
  # The ID of an object
  id: ID!
  countryId: Int
  phonePrefix: String
  name: String
  timezone: String
}

# Representation of date and time in "Y-m-d H:i:s" format
scalar DateTime

interface NodeInterface {
  # The ID of an object
  id: ID!
}

type Query {
  # Fetches an object given its ID
  node(
    # The ID of an object
    id: ID!
  ): NodeInterface
  viewer: User
  countries: [Country]
}

type User implements NodeInterface {
  # The ID of an object
  id: ID!
  username: String
  userId: Int
  lastLoginDateTime: DateTime
}
```

**SampleRoute.js** -used as the first route when someone opens React app

```
import Relay from 'react-relay';

export default class extends Relay.Route {
    static queries = {
        countries: () => Relay.QL`
            query AppHomeRoute { 
                viewer
            }
    `,
    };
    static routeName = 'AppHomeRoute';
}
```

**App.js** I want to have countries list in Index component, Ideally in App js I don't want to event pass countries with props but I want them to be in Index component which will be renamed to CountryList in the future

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Relay from 'react-relay';
import Index from './page/index';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <Index country={this.props.countries} />
    );
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(App, {
  fragments: {
    countries: () => Relay.QL`
    countries {
        ${Index.getFragment('country')}
      }
    }
            // fragment F1 on Country {
            //   ${Index.getFragment('country')}
            // },
            
        `
  }
});
```

Now I get an error:

**SampleRoute.js:5 Uncaught Error: GraphQL validation error ``Cannot query field "viewer" on type "Query"**

which I completely don't understand because when I query the server with graphiql then it works okay.

**Query:**

```
{
  viewer {
    id
    username
  }
  node(id:"dXNlcjo2NjY=") {
    id
    username
  }
  countries {
    name
  }
}
```

**response:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "id": "dXNlcjo2NjY=",
      "username": "Robert"
    },
    "node": {
      "id": "dXNlcjo2NjY=",
      "username": "Robert"
    },
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "AFGHANISTAN"
      },
      {
        "name": "ALBANIA"
      }, (...)
    ]
   }
}
```

Comment: do you mean inside viewer you want articletype data with the nodeinterface, globalid from graphql-relayjs

Comment: @p0k8_ I've updated question and put more details. I don't want to have it inside viewer I'm not sure if I should have another type of Countries where it's list of country, then if so how to connect it with relay or maybe I should create some type and put it to node.

Comment: please can  you make a gist of `schema`, `rootquery` and `types`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rpodwika/ae1f613fb07cadfcd2b6fcc87fdfd7e2 I wonder maybe I should create some type that can be fetched by node type and in this type add edge connection to list of countries?

Comment: yes create a type along with the relay `globalIdfield`  field to fetch and for `object identification` and`nodeInterface` for the `edges` connections and better pagination. And in your `RootQuery` you have use `node: nodeField` in fields along with the `types` fields, later, you have to use fragments in the `node` to fetch and get the data from `relayId`, this is as part of mine graphql-js.

Comment: if you want i can put some graphql-js code

Comment: @p0k8_ if you could I'd be very grateful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136529/discussion-between-robert-and-p0k8).